# Into what options have I to put the --stacktrace for Gradle if it is NOT an Android project?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Soon after starting a task I have got a message:

```
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Yes, there are two discussions here about how I can do it in command line, thank you. I am using IDE not for returning back to command line constantly. There should be some possibilities how to set that options in the settings for Run or for Project. But I cannot find any.

I can go to Gradle-Android compiler and nicely set --stacktrace there. Several posts on SO describe that in variations. But my project is not Android. And on the settings page is written:

```
These settings are used for compiling Gradle-based Android projects.
```

There are interesting pages in:

```
 File-Settings-Build...-Compiler, 
      User-Local ... VM options
 File-Settings-Build...-Compiler-Java Compiler-
      Additionals command line parameters
 Run-Edit-Gradle-*task*-
      VM options
      Script parameters
```

I can't put --stacktrace in VM parameters, it is an error. Maybe it is possible with some special syntax?

Where and what to set?

Answer (score 3):

For intellij Idea 2021.1.2:

1. Run -> Edit Configurations... -> /*select your test*/
2. `Arguments` filed should have something like `--tests "e2eflow.StatsTest.testName"`
3. Add --debug or --stacktrace at the end of it

Answer (score 1):

This should be used for setting:

```
Run-Edit-Gradle-*task*-
  Script parameters
```

Both --stacktrace and --debug work there